# Crash pngData() as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

```
 func artWorkItem(imageToShow: UIImage) -> AVMetadataItem? {
        let item = AVMutableMetadataItem()
        item.value = imageToShow.pngData() as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
        item.dataType = kCMMetadataBaseDataType_PNG as String
        item.identifier = AVMetadataIdentifier.commonIdentifierArtwork
        item.extendedLanguageTag = "und"
        return item.copy() as? AVMetadataItem
    }
```

From crash organizer stack trace crash occurs at line “item.value = imageToShow.pngData() as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?” States specialized AVMetaData.artWorkItem(imageToShow:) +252.
It also shows info like “specialized static Data_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC()”.Could not replicate the crash. What could be the reason for the crash ?. Is it some memory issue? . Used kingfisher library to download the image contents.

Comment: is `pngData()` a method in extension to `UIImage` what does it return? Does return type actually confirms to both NSCopying and NSObjectProtocol? Also why not simply cast it as NSObject (which obviously confirms `NSObjectProtocol` and also confirms to `NSCopying `protocol

Comment: yes, " public func pngData() -> Data? // return image as PNG. May return nil if image has no CGImageRef or invalid bitmap format". Yes, could use just NSData. But the reason for the crash is not known. Could not replicate it. Tried with big size image and nil value image but no crash. Any help?